# Books to learn tensor product on hilbert spaces

Tags: soft-question, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, quantum-computation

I have just started to work on Quantum Computing.  I have began to read a paper which deals with tensor product on hilbert spaces.

I have a had a course in functional analysis. So I don't have an issue with the part involving hilbert spaces. We were following the book by Martin Schechter.

I need some suggestions on books which I need, to follow tensor products on hilbert spaces (in general upto $ k $ products).

Is there any book other than "An Introduction to Quantum Stochastica Calculus, K.R.Parthasarathy" ??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: An Introduction to Quantum Stochastica Calculus, K.R.Parthasarathy.